# Access files from NFS mount with service account in kubernetes pod

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kubernetes-helm

I am looking for some help/suggestions with kubernetes. I am trying to mount an NFS shared drive to the docker container running inside a kubernetes pod so that I can access the files inside that drive from code that runs inside the docker container. I was able to successfully mount the drive and I am able to see that based on the kubectl logs for the running pod.

But my problem is that only a service account has access to the contents of the folder I need to access and I am not sure how to use the service account to access the files. I am totally new to the the kubernetes world and trying to understand and learn how this kind of scenarios are handled. I used helm charts for configuring the NFS mount.

Answer (score 1):

So generally mounting directly inside a Docker container is not the greatest solution.

What you should rather look at when mounting data, is to create a PersistentVolume and PersistentClaim in Kubernetes and mount that to the pod. This abstract Storage specifics from your application specifics.

You can find more information on the Kubernetes [blog](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

In [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#lifecycle-of-a-volume-and-claim) they explain about using NFS.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Security Context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/). More specifically, fsGroup is used to define the Volume owner.